# How to dynamically render react components?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I have a website where if I press a button it fetches a post object from a database and adds it into an array. I need to somehow display all the objects in the array as react components and also to update the list every time when a new post is added.

I've been trying to use the map() method but I can't get it to display the new posts that are added when I click the button.

Main component:

```
import Post from './Post'
import { useState, useEffect, createElement } from 'react'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import Axios from 'axios'


const Content = () => {

    const [postArr, setPostArr] = useState([])

    const getPosts = ()=>{
        Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
        Axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:3010/api/getpost/',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata' }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            addPostToPostArray(response)
        })
        .catch((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
    const addPostToPostArray = (response) => {
        let imgName = response.data.imgurl.slice(68, 999999)
        let sendObj = {
            id:response.data.id,
            posterid:response.data.posterid,
            imgurl:`http://localhost:3010/images/${imgName}`,
            title:response.data.title,
            likes:response.data.likes,
            date:response.data.date
        }
        postArr.push(sendObj)

        /*
        A fetched post will look like this:
        {
        id:123, posterid:321, imgurl:`http://localhost:3010/images/333.png`,
        title:'best title', likes:444, date:111111
        }
        */
    }

    return ( 
        <div>
            {postArr.map((e) => {
                return <Post post={e}/>
            })}
            <button onClick={getPosts}>load post</button>   
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Content;
```

Post component:

```
const Post = (props) => {

    const post = props.post

    return ( 
            <div className='post-frame'>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                <div className="image-frame">
                    <img src={post.imgurl}></img>
                </div>
                <p>{post.likes}</p>
                <p>{post.posterid}</p>
            </div>                                 
    );
}
 
export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the state of the component you need to call that setPostArr function with the updated array. Without that the state of the component never get's updated.

Here's an example

```js
const Content = () => {

    const [postArr, setPostArr] = useState([])

    const getPosts = () => {
        ...
    }

    const addPostToPostArray = (response) => {
        let sendObj = {
            ...
        }

        // ~ This part here
        setPostArr([...postArr, sendObj])
        
       // ~ Instead of
       // postArr.push(sendObj)
    }

    return ...
}
```